# Zend_Paginator + Query Paramenter (ZF1)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I am using the ZF1 with Zend_Paginator but if I have a search that brings all data without filter, works perfectly, but if I have a query filter paging works only on the first page.

```
   public function getConsultaTelefones($setor)
       {      

          if ($setor != "") {

           $select = $this->select()
                 ->setIntegrityCheck ( false )
                 ->from ( array('t' => 'sca_telefone'))      
                 ->joinInner ( array ('p' => 'sca_posto'), 't.idPosto = p.idPosto')   
                 ->joinInner ( array ('l' => 'sca_lotacao'), 't.idLotacao = l.idLotacao')   
                 ->where("l.idLotacao = ?", $setor) ;   

          $resultado = $this->fetchAll($select);

          } else {

             $select = $this->select()
                 ->setIntegrityCheck ( false )
                 ->from ( array('t' => 'sca_telefone'))      
                 ->joinInner ( array ('p' => 'sca_posto'), 't.idPosto = p.idPosto')   
                 ->joinInner ( array ('l' => 'sca_lotacao'), 't.idLotacao = l.idLotacao');

          $resultado = $this->fetchAll($select);

          }

       return $resultado;

       }
```

In the parameter $ sector it brings all the data as the filter and creates the correct pagination, but only the first page because if I click the next or last page he "recreates" the paging all table data.

```
public function paginacaoConsulta($dados)
   {
      $pagina = intval($this->_getParam('pagina', 1));

      $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($dados);
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5);
        $paginator->setPageRange(7);
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($pagina);

        $this->view->paginator = $paginator;   

    }

   public function consultarAction()
   {
      $setor = $this->_getParam('setor');

      $modLotacao = new Sca_Model_Lotacao('sca');

      $resultado = $modLotacao->getConsultaTelefones($setor);

      $this->paginacaoConsulta($resultado);
        }
```

Already researched several things but nothing has met me. Please I need help.

Follow the rest of the codes:

```
<?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator, 'Sliding', 'paginacao.phtml'); ?>



<nav>
  <ul class="pagination">

    <li>

    <!-- Link para a primeira página -->
    <?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
        <a title="Primeira Página" href="<?php echo $this->url(array('pagina' => $this->first)); ?>" aria-label="Previous">&laquo; Primeira</a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <a class="current" title="Primeira Página" href="<?php echo $this->url(array('pagina' => $this->first)); ?>" aria-label="Previous">&laquo; Primeira</a>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </li>

    <li>

        <?php if ($this->pageCount): ?>

        <?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>

          <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('pagina' => $this->previous)); ?>" aria-label="Previous">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
          </a>

        <?php else: ?>

          <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </li> 

    <li>

        <?php foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $pagina): ?>

          <?php if ($pagina != $this->current): ?>

            <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('pagina' => $pagina)); ?>">
                <?php echo $pagina; ?>
            </a>

          <?php else: ?>

            <a href="#"><?php echo $pagina; ?></a>

          <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </li>

    <li>

        <?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>

          <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('pagina' => $this->next)); ?>" aria-label="Next" >
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
          </a>

        <?php else: ?>
          <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </li>

    <li>

    <!-- Última página -->
    <?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
        <a title="Última Página" href="<?php echo $this->url(array('pagina' => $this->last)); ?>" aria-label="Next">Última &raquo;</a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <a class="current" title="Última Página" href="<?php echo $this->url(array('pagina' => $this->last)); ?>" aria-label="Next">Última &raquo;</a>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass to query param in next and previous link. Like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('pagina' => $this->previous, 'setor' => $this->setor)); ?>" aria-label="Previous">
```

and pass it to the view:

```
$this->view->setor = $this->_getParam('setor');
```